# Split and rename single file into multiple files using keywords present in file

Tags: linux, windows, awk, sed, rename

New to awk like commands. I have single text file holding SQL DDL's in below format.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $database.TABLE_A ;
...
...

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $database.TABLE_B ;
...
...
```

Would like to split single file into multiple files as

1. TABLE_A.SQL
2. TABLE_B.SQL
3. TABLE_X.SQL

I am able to get the table names from single file with the help of below awk command. Still struggling to split and rename file with `TABLE_X.SQL` name.

```
awk 'FNR==1 {split($5,a,"."); print a[2]}' *.SQL
```

> I am using Windows 10 DOS shell.

Comment: It is a good practice to add a comment and then downvote. This helps user understand how this question can be improved or is it really a dumb question to be closed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to acheive desired output with the help of below Shell script, which we can run in Windows bash shell ...

```
#!/bin/bash

#Split single file
awk '/DROP/{x="F"++i;}{print > x".TXT";}' $1

#Create output directory
mkdir -p ./_output

#Move file by chaning extention
for f in *.TXT ; do
  newfilename=$(awk 'FNR==1 {split($5,a,"."); print a[2]}' "$f")
  echo Processed $f ... new file is $newfilename".SQL" ...
       mv $f ./_output/$newfilename".SQL"      
done
```

Comment: Need to change your split step as it leaves the files open and will error out: `awk '/DROP/{close(x".TXT");x="F"++i;}{print > x".TXT";}' $1`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/DROP/{if(file){close(file)};match($0,/TABLE_[^ ]*/);file=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)".SQL"} {print > (file)}' Input_file
```

Comment: Syntax error,  ^ unexpected newline or end of string. Replaced  input file with single file available.

Comment: @Aditya, This command worked perfectly fine for me, please paste what exactly are you running ?

Comment: @Aditya, in case of file name passing as a variable us something like `awk '/DROP/{if(file){close(file)};match($0,/TABLE_[^ ]*/);file=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)".SQL"} {print > (file)}'  "$var"`.

Comment: Don't know if it's related but OP runs this on a Windows environment

Comment: @Aditya, I am sorry I haven't tested this on windows env. Thanks Oguz ismail for letting know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 File name that I am going to pass can be hardcoded. From that single file, command should split it into multiple files along with name to be picked up from the keyword present in that file. The required keyword I am getting from above command.

Comment: @Aditya, yes this command works for me when I created an Input_file and ran this command against it, it is creating output files, though I checked it on bash not on windows.

Comment: @Aditya, Could you please do let me know if you are using cygwin? I am not sure if DOS supports awk or not.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I am using the command prompt (cmd) on Windows 10. Honestly not sure how to check if it is POSIX compliant or not. But awk\sed commands work on this barring few exceptions or error that I am getting with above command.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "[. ]" '{print >($(NF-1)".SQL")}' file.sql
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain what the code does and how it helps.

Comment: Below is the exact error output that I am getting. I simply replaced file.sql with export.sql, actual file :- awk: cmd. line:1: {print  export.SQL
awk: cmd. line:1:               ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print  export.SQL
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: @Aditya those errors are related to the shell you're using. I think you should add more details to your question about the environment you're working on

Comment: @oguzismail, I am running the commands on windows 10 DOS shell.